# Add color to carrier column to order table in Prestashop administrative office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Add the carriers column, and to the table 'ps_carrier_lang' add a column named 'color' as in the statuses, I want that color to be displayed.

```
    'carrierdelay' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Envio'), 
    'type' => 'text',
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
    'color' => 'color',
    'filter_key' => 'carrier_lang!delay',  
    'filter_type' => 'text',
    'order_key' => 'carrier_lang!delay'         
),
```

if I put    'color' => 'color',it will bring me the same color of the order status, but I want to define another type of color to the carriers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a callback:

```
...
'carrierdelay' => array(
    'title' => $this->l('Envio'), 
    'type' => 'text',
    'align' => 'text-center',
    'class' => 'fixed-width-xl',
    'color' => 'color',
    'filter_key' => 'carrier_lang!delay',  
    'filter_type' => 'text',
    'order_key' => 'carrier_lang!delay'         
    'callback' => 'colorCarrier'         
),
...

function colorCarrier($value, $object) {
    if ($object['carrierdelay'] > 3) { // Do the compare that you need, and set desired colors
        $backgroundColor = '#4169E1';
        $color = 'white';
    }

    // Return span with color and string
    return '<span class="label color_field" style="background-color:'.$backgroundColor.';color:'.$white.'">'.$this->l("Delayed").'</span>';
}
```